Needed: reverse-motion linkage for confined space
I'm trying to design a mechanism for a (manually operated) two-point door latch that needs to fit in a very small space (nominally 1.25"×1.25"×N" with no tolerance allowance). The latches need to move synchronously in opposite directions about 0.625" using a single, preferably linear, actuation system. (Due to a combination of the tight space, assembly considerations, and the need for external actuation, I'm using custom-designed latches, but they're very similar in both principle and size to bog-standard tubular mortise latches or comparable slam latches.)
Off-the-shelf two-point latch systems are around 2" wide.
I have this sketchy-seeming idea for a cam system:

(16 squares = 1". Black is the cross-section of the tube this needs to fit inside.)
However, I'd also really like the actuation to be toward the reversing mechanism, and I'm not sure how to do that with this. Nor am I very confident in the design as shown. (For one, the action distance is barely sufficient; the rods are going to have to be of very precise length for this to work.)
Could a rack-and-pinion fit in this space (and not be overly painful to manufacture)? Is there some other form of reversing linkage that has a better travel-to-width ratio? (Would a cable-and-pulley setup be sufficiently reliable and durable for a door-latch mechanism? The goal is similar reliability as an bog-standard door mechanism, so probably around 10k operations without maintenance or about 10 years of "typical" use.)

this may help ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=left+right+double+end+screw&iax=images&ia=images

@jsotola... um, are you thinking of something along those lines but with a very steep thread pitch? Otherwise it's not clear how one of those would even apply to my problem, much less be practical for a door latch. How reliable would one of those be when using linear motion to drive rotation, rather than the other way around?

use rotation to drive linear motion ... the two ends have opposite thread orientation ... the sliding parts would move in opposite directions when the threaded rod was rotated ... the threaded sections can be further apart

@jsotola, I think you missed the preference for linear actuation. Also, this is for the latching system of a door, and a manually operated one at that. I would be very, very concerned about the degree of step-up that would be needed to turn a reasonable input rotation (90°) into enough rotation on a "typical" screw to get the required travel. Plus, where does that step-up fit? The "best" way I see your idea working would be with 45° screw thread to balance one side turning linear motion into rotational motion while the other side does the opposite. It might work, but how reliably?

@jsotola, I should give credit, that is a much more space-efficient mechanism to turn rotational motion into linear motion in two opposed directions. What I'm really looking for, however, is something to turn linear motion in one direction into linear motion in the opposite direction.
